# How to slice a three dimensional array in three for in loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a three dimensional array like this:

```
        let insPerDay = []
        let insDuringThisWeek = [];
        let  insDuringThisWeek_temp = [[], [], [], [], [], [], []]; 
        for (var i = 0; i < spaceIterationInsWeek.length; i++){
            // this loop will repeat a variable amount of times but in this example it repeats twice   
            for (let k=0; k<weekArray.length; k++) {
            // will repeat a variable amount of times but in this example it repeats 7 times    
                for (let j = 0; j < spaceIterationInsWeek[i].length; j ++) {
                // will repeat a variable amount of time (I think in this case it's 167 times, 104 the first loop, 63 the second);
                    if (spaceIterationInsWeek[i][j] > weekArray[k][0] && spaceIterationInsWeek[i][j] < weekArray[k][1]) {
                        insDuringThisWeek_temp[k].push(spaceIterationInsWeek[i][j]);    
                    }   
                } 
                insDuringThisWeek.push(insDuringThisWeek_temp[k]);                                     
            }     

             console.log(insDuringThisWeek.slice()); 
            insPerDay.push(insDuringThisWeek.slice());
            console.log(insPerDay);                
        // insDuringThisWeek.push(insDuringThisWeek_temp);                            
        }
```

For now I the console.is logging this:

[image]

Notice that the first time the child loop runs, the **insDuringThisWeek.slice()** is logging **Array(28)**, but inside, when I expand the view, it actually states **36** and not *28*. I know this is related with the fact that arrays are passed by reference, and that is why I am trying to use slice() to prevent that.

In the end the intended result should be:
**1 parent array** with **2 child arrays** each with **7 grandchild arrays**. Then those **7 grandchild arrays** should have different lenghts...

something like:

```
(2) [Array(7), Array(7)]
    > 0: (7) [Array(28), Array(12), Array(8), Array(0), Array(0), Array(50), Array(6)]
    > 1: (7) [Array(8), Array(11), Array(3), Array(0), Array(0), Array(37), Array(4)]
```

Now the arrays are adding up like this:

```
(2) [Array(7), Array(14)]
    > 0: (7) [Array(36), Array(23), Array(11), Array(0), Array(0), Array(87), Array(10)]
    > 1: (14) [Array(36), Array(23), Array(11), Array(0), Array(0), Array(87), Array(10), Array(36), Array(23), Array(11), Array(0), Array(0), Array(87), Array(10)]
```

Is there a way to do achieve this using three loop logic?

"Copy/pastable" data for **spaceIterationInsWeek**:

```
  var spaceIterationInsWeek = [["1538032574112", "1538032574299", "1538032574489", "1538032574707", "1538032574958", "1538032580589", "1538032580744", "1538032583050", "1538035431634", "1538035432105", "1538044237902", "1538044253095", "1538089207793", "1538089207972", "1538089208184", "1538089209765", "1538089209935", "1538089210172", "1538140319898", "1538140320415", "1538393131974", "1538393132133", "1538393132301", "1538393134682", "1538419054736", "1538419056057", "1538419056445", "1538421078992", "1538423320582", "1538423324199", "1538423328179", "1538423331484", "1538423472877", "1538423584874", "1538423586801", "1538423604206", "1538423664249", "1538423668981", "1538423682914", "1538423691802", "1538423866031", "1538423867420", "1538423868327", "1538423875373", "1538424176251", "1538424179511", "1538424231217", "1538424283692", "1538424327861", "1538424327866", "1538424327868", "1538424327871", "1538424327877", "1538424327882", "1538424327884", "1538424327891", "1538424327896", "1538426250753", "1538426251268", "1538426251642", "1538428174561", "1538428174925", "1538428175168", "1538428179449", "1538428179612", "1538428185771", "1538428199625", "1538428204510", "1538428204700", "1538428204883", "1538497882619", "1538498290347", "1538498319612", "1538498370580", "1538498465625", "1538498510231"],["1538033851202", "1538035355166", "1538035355949", "1538035370713", "1538043037913", "1538043065714", "1538043065993", "1538043530533", "1538043531900", "1538043533828", "1538044225832", "1538089267124", "1538089267318", "1538089267543", "1538393117968", "1538393118102", "1538393118254", "1538393119966", "1538393120110", "1538393120362", "1538393120538", "1538393120722", "1538414187921", "1538414188175", "1538414188327", "1538414191291", "1538414191516", "1538424651376", "1538424672070", "1538424672073", "1538424672077", "1538424672080", "1538424673236", "1538424673238", "1538424673241", "1538424673244", "1538424679001", "1538424679010", "1538424679014", "1538424679017", "1538428236679", "1538428236846", "1538428237012", "1538428237172", "1538428237341", "1538428237491", "1538428237649", "1538428237816", "1538428237982", "1538428238159", "1538428238334", "1538498266744", "1538498341583", "1538498481082", "1538498494065"]]
```

"Copy/pastable" data for **weekArray** :

```
   var weekArray = [[1538002800000, 1538089200000], [1538089200000, 1538175600000],[1538175600000, 1538262000000], [1538262000000, 1538348400000],[1538348400000, 1538434800000],[1538434800000, 1538521200000],[1538521200000, 1538607600000]]
```

Comment: Can we get some copy-pastable sample data for `spaceIterationInsWeek` and `weekArray`?

Comment: @mpen I have put it in the question.

Comment: Those aren't copy-pastable. Paste that into Chrome dev tools/console and you will get a JS syntax error.

Comment: Give me one minute then

Comment: You can use `JSON.stringify(data)` to get nice output if you need to. We don't need the whole thing, just enough to work with.

Comment: Updated it. Please see if that works now. Many thanks @mpen
The numbers I'm getting now on my program are slightly different from when I posted the question. The hour/day has changed on my timezone (the program logic changes the data sets dynamically depending on the time) but the logic of the loops above remains the same.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm just trying to understand what you're trying to do... `weekArray` appears to be an array of start-of-day/end-of-day pairs (24 hours apart). And then `spaceIterationInsWeek` is... what? What are you trying to do? Find timestamps within each day range? What are the two subarrays in `spaceIterationInsWeek`?

Comment: @mpen I think I got it. Many thank for all your effort. I am sorry if I made you waste time on this and do let me know if you see any error on my answer

Comment: Yes. that's extacly it. spaceIterationArray is a previous array with all different timestamps split in two spaces/departments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach...... may or may not be the exact output you were looking for.

```js
var spaceIterationInsWeek = [
  ["1538032574112", "1538032574299", "1538032574489", "1538032574707", "1538032574958", "1538032580589", "1538032580744", "1538032583050", "1538035431634", "1538035432105", "1538044237902", "1538044253095", "1538089207793", "1538089207972", "1538089208184", "1538089209765", "1538089209935", "1538089210172", "1538140319898", "1538140320415", "1538393131974", "1538393132133", "1538393132301", "1538393134682", "1538419054736", "1538419056057", "1538419056445", "1538421078992", "1538423320582", "1538423324199", "1538423328179", "1538423331484", "1538423472877", "1538423584874", "1538423586801", "1538423604206", "1538423664249", "1538423668981", "1538423682914", "1538423691802", "1538423866031", "1538423867420", "1538423868327", "1538423875373", "1538424176251", "1538424179511", "1538424231217", "1538424283692", "1538424327861", "1538424327866", "1538424327868", "1538424327871", "1538424327877", "1538424327882", "1538424327884", "1538424327891", "1538424327896", "1538426250753", "1538426251268", "1538426251642", "1538428174561", "1538428174925", "1538428175168", "1538428179449", "1538428179612", "1538428185771", "1538428199625", "1538428204510", "1538428204700", "1538428204883", "1538497882619", "1538498290347", "1538498319612", "1538498370580", "1538498465625", "1538498510231"],
  ["1538033851202", "1538035355166", "1538035355949", "1538035370713", "1538043037913", "1538043065714", "1538043065993", "1538043530533", "1538043531900", "1538043533828", "1538044225832", "1538089267124", "1538089267318", "1538089267543", "1538393117968", "1538393118102", "1538393118254", "1538393119966", "1538393120110", "1538393120362", "1538393120538", "1538393120722", "1538414187921", "1538414188175", "1538414188327", "1538414191291", "1538414191516", "1538424651376", "1538424672070", "1538424672073", "1538424672077", "1538424672080", "1538424673236", "1538424673238", "1538424673241", "1538424673244", "1538424679001", "1538424679010", "1538424679014", "1538424679017", "1538428236679", "1538428236846", "1538428237012", "1538428237172", "1538428237341", "1538428237491", "1538428237649", "1538428237816", "1538428237982", "1538428238159", "1538428238334", "1538498266744", "1538498341583", "1538498481082", "1538498494065"]
]

var weekArray = [
  [1538002800000, 1538089200000],
  [1538089200000, 1538175600000],
  [1538175600000, 1538262000000],
  [1538262000000, 1538348400000],
  [1538348400000, 1538434800000],
  [1538434800000, 1538521200000],
  [1538521200000, 1538607600000]
]


var out = spaceIterationInsWeek.map(space => {
  let grouped = Array.from({
    length: weekArray.length
  }).map(_ => []); // create an empty array for each week pair
  
  space.forEach(ts => {
    let idx = weekArray.findIndex(([start, end]) => ts >= start && ts < end); // find which day the space falls into
    if (idx >= 0) {
      grouped[idx].push(ts); // group it using the week-pair's index
    } else {
      console.error(`Timestamp ${ts} not found in any week array`) // if no time range found, error!
    }
  })
  return grouped;
})

console.log(out);
```

Comment: I'll give this one a go as soon as possible so I can mark as correct. Many many thanks @mpen.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to clear the array at the end:

```
        let insPerDay = []
        let insDuringThisWeek = [];
        let  insDuringThisWeek_temp = [[], [], [], [], [], [], []]; // clean array
        for (var i = 0; i < spaceIterationInsWeek.length; i++){
            // will repeat the number of depts (i =2)  

            for (let k=0; k<weekArray.length; k++) {
            // will repeat 7 times  (j =7)   
                for (let j = 0; j < spaceIterationInsWeek[i].length; j ++) {
                // will repeat the number of ins
                    if (spaceIterationInsWeek[i][j] > weekArray[k][0] && spaceIterationInsWeek[i][j] < weekArray[k][1]) {
                        insDuringThisWeek_temp[k].push(spaceIterationInsWeek[i][j]);    
                    }   

                } 
                insDuringThisWeek.push(insDuringThisWeek_temp[k].slice());   
                console.log(insDuringThisWeek);             

            }     
            insPerDay.push(insDuringThisWeek);
        //HERE
            insDuringThisWeek = [];
            insDuringThisWeek_temp = [[], [], [], [], [], [], []];
            console.log(insPerDay);


        }
```